# z-score to investigate the significance of the difference between population mean and one value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, z-score

Let's say I have two populations: serbian men (mean height = 182 cm, SD = 6.74 cm) and vietnamese men (mean height = 162 cm, SD = 5.4 cm). There is one vietnamese who says: "I'm not a vietnamese, I'm a serbian". His height is 155 cm.
We count the z-score and see that it's equal to -4.006, which means there are only 0.003% of serbs who are as short as him or even shorter. 
Can we say that we rejected the null hypothesis (which says that our x, the vietnamese's height, was drawn from the distribution of the serbians' heights) and our man is most likely not a serbian?
In other words, can we use the z-score as a  statistical test? Can we say that p=0.003?

Answer (score 1):

It would be controversial to assign a preliminary probability that the speaker is telling the truth or not. Even though a lie would seem to imply that he is or is not a Serb, we would need some other assurances to be sure of that conclusion. After all, we must know that the speaker could not possibly be not a Serbian woman posing as a man, a Sicilian of average stature, or myriad other problems that accompany uttering falsehoods. That is, how do we know how deep the falsehood goes? It it one lie, or is the only the tip of the iceberg? Once we abandon the truth, we also abandon logic, which latter is only guaranteed to conserve truth values, not falsehoods.

Comment: So, we can't say that he's most likely not a setbian man? Let's imagine he didn't lie, we just found his charred corpse and desided to check if he was a serbian man.

Comment: Well, if you change the question you do change the answer. In that latter case you could calculate a probability, but I would not only do that. I would look in the mouth to see who did the dental work, at the pelvis to determine sex, at the DNA, if available to see the world regional bio-markers, sex and so forth, and last but not least, If I found the body in Serbia, on a raft in the Pacific, or somewhere else, that might tend to hone my guesswork a bit more.